# I need help looping this program if the user inputs something invalid

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I don't know how to loop this simple program I coded and I really need help.

This is in my first class:

```
public class project{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        dank dankObject = new dank();

        dankObject.design();
        dankObject.catchError();

    }
}
```

This is my second class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dank{
    public void design(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| Main Checmicals in Substances |");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| LSD | SHROOMS | WEED |");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.print("\nWhich substance would you like to learn about?\nInput: ");
    }

    public void catchError(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        try{
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("LSD"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Lysergic Acid Diethylamide");
                System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("SHROOMS"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Psilocybin");
                System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("WEED"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: THC");
                System.out.println("Fatal: HELL NO");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
        }

    }
}
```

Basically I just want the program to restart if the user enters an invalid input. Do I do this with while loop? I'm just beginning to learn java.

Comment: @MadPhysicist why? Looks good to me.

Comment: Nothing in the try-catch throws an exception.

Comment: Exception isn't a checked type exception, you can catch it even if nothing explicitly declares that it throws it.

Comment: It does compile, even though he doesn't follow some best practices. It doesn't do anything though.

Comment: Hint: make catchError return a boolean (value: true if input is valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the two lines:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = input.nextLine();
```

into the end of the design() method. Then call the the `catchError(choice)` method and pass choice into it. Put the line `design()` in at the end your catch body. Finally, take the `catchError()` method out of your main().

This is just a suggestion, you can do anything that looks like this if you prefer. I'm also not using a boolean so if you want to do that instead, you should probably take some other suggestions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dank{
    public void design(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| Main Checmicals in Substances |");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| LSD | SHROOMS | WEED |");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.print("\nWhich substance would you like to learn about?\nInput: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        catchError(choice);
    }

    public void catchError(String choice){
        try{
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("LSD"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Lysergic Acid Diethylamide");
                System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("SHROOMS"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Psilocybin");
                System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("WEED"))
            {
                System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: THC");
                System.out.println("Fatal: HELL NO");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
                design();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
            design();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any recommendations on how I can shorten my code or make it better?

Comment: The code may not seem like it, but it's already pretty short. Just a lot of text that you're outputting onto the screen (which makes it seem longer). The code itself is solid though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to loop if the input is invalid.

In that case, change your `catchError` method to return `boolean` instead of `void` and return whether the input was valid, as such:

```
public boolean catchError(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = input.nextLine();
    try{
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("LSD"))
        {
            System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Lysergic Acid Diethylamide");
            System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("SHROOMS"))
        {
            System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: Psilocybin");
            System.out.println("Fatal: NO");
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("WEED"))
        {
            System.out.println("\nMain Chemical: THC");
            System.out.println("Fatal: HELL NO");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\nInvalid Input!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then loop while the return value is false:

```
boolean flag = true;
while (flag) {
    dankObject.design();
    flag = dankObject.catchError();
}
```